# Can you access objects by using their names as a string, instead of a object?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I don't know if I explained this in my title, this is what i want to do.
(In VB on a active server page)
I have 5 buttons called but1.....but2.
Right now I have the following code to make them invisible

```
but1.Visible=false;
but2.Visible=false;
but3.Visible=false;
but4.Visible=false;
but5.Visible=false,
```

Is there a way to access the objects by using a string, example

```
for(i=i;i<6;i++
       items("but"+str(i)).visible=false
```

Comment: Please put some more effort into asking a question in a readable, well-formatted way - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Did you accidentally put caps lock on halfway through or something? You should really proofread before posting.

Comment: Ah, the power of vb.net, it isn't case sensitive.  Drives C# programmers nuts.  Replace "items" with Me.Controls.  Or me.controls :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a container control like an [`ASP.NET Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) that is rendered as a [DIV](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) when they have a similar meaning:

```
   <asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonPanel">
       <asp:TextBox id="Txt1" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button id="Btn1" Text="click me" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server"/><br />
       <asp:TextBox id="Txt2" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button id="Btn2" Text="click me" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server"/><br />
       <asp:TextBox id="Txt3" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button id="Btn3" Text="click me" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server"/>
   </asp:Panel>
```

Then you can find and loop them in this way:

```
Dim allPanelButtons = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
For Each btn In allPanelButtons 
    btn.Visible = False
Next
```

[`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) would also work on the whole page, but not when they're nested in child controls(like `GridView`).

Your question is a bit unclear, of course you can reference controls by their name(actually the ID)directly when they're added declaratively to the page's `ControlCollection`:

```
Btn1.Visible = False
```

And yes, it works also to search them by id, but **i don't recommend this approach** because it's not fail-safe and can cause future problems that happen only on runtime. So just for the sake of completeness:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    Dim control = FindControl("Btn" & i)
    If control IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf control Is Button Then
        control.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you, yes you answered my quastion, I did n ot really know how to ask it.